# React router automatically redirecting to page that is not root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm facing an issue with my react routing. The code below causes my app to automatically start with the Foo page, which I wish would start on Home page ('/' instead of '/foo').

**Index.js**

```
function Index() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default Index;
```

**Routes.js**

```
const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
            <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
)

export default Routes
```

**Home.js**

```
...
<Router>
    <Link className="link" to="/foo">+</Link>
</Router>
...
```

I checked time and time again, read documentation and example codes and they are all doing the same as me, but for some reason mine renders '/foo' instead of '/' as it's starting page.
What am I doing wrong? How can I make this code start at '/' instead of '/foo'?

**Edit**
@TJ's answer was correct and order did change the behavior and now '/' is being matched and rendering the Home component. However, the link on the Home.js chunk of code is changing the url to '/foo' but the Foo component is not rendered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was at two points:
First, the one TJ pointed out in his answers about the order of the routes and their respective paths. The other one was really a dumb mistake I made. Turns out this was my index.js:

```
function Index() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

When it should have been this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes />
        <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And both within Home.js and Foo.js I had their own ReactDOM.render method being called. So what was happening was that the route was never being used anyway. React was just rendering whichever component I called last since it had its own rendering method. Rookie mistake, but I hope it helps if anyone has the same issue.

Thank you TJ for the support.

Answer (score 2):

Add `exact` for specific routes like `/foo` and put your generic route at the bottom like:

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} exact />
   <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hi, TJ. Tried that, same behavior. I even changed the order in which I import those components (Home came before Foo, now Foo comes first)

Comment: It worked! For some reason I had to restart the server, but know it does redirect to the right page '/'. I'm now facing a different issue. Please refer to 'Home.js' on the question. That link is inputing '/foo' on the URL, however, the component is not rendered.

Comment: when the link is clicked, what is the URL in your browser status bar? Can you share a sample? (after removing any sensitive info)

Comment: Also it might be useful to share a sample of `Foo` component

Answer (score -1):

It looks to all Routes one by one from top to bottom until it matches exactly with one. In your case, it matches with foo.

Prefer using like this;

```
const Routes = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
)

export default Routes;
```

I highly recommend you spend some time on the official document to understand things clearly.

see https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing

Comment: Op already stated *"read documentation and example codes"*